# Foresee ssd disk driver for windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ssd

In teclast x3 pro, I reinstall windows 10 from usb boot stick(make from iso). At disk partion step, internal ssd is missing. My internal ssd is
Foresee
m.2242
128GB

Is it need to install driver?Please help me where I find driver for this?

I install all driver from this pages!!

http://techtablets.com/teclast-x3-pro/downloads/

What driver do I need?
And also I cannot enter into uefi-setting!!(By ESC)
Help me!!!!!!

Comment: Do you need to install a driver:No; your problem isn't caused by a missing driver

Answer (score 0):

If the drive is missing, it isn't because of a driver issue. It is because of a formatting or hardware issue with the hard drive itself. To solve, you would need to troubleshooot formatting issues.

The best way that I solve the issue with new drives not showing up, is I attach the drive to a computer and run the Live CD of gParted.

In gParted, you can diagnose if the hard drive has a hardware problem.

If you do not see the drive in gParted, except in very rare cases, you probably have a bad drive and you should return it or exchange the drive for a replacement immediately.

However, if the drive shows up in gParted, all is good, now you probably just need to set up the partition tables and format it. How to do this is beyond the scope of this question, you could create a new question if you need help how to do that.

After formatting the new drive, exit gParted and now boot into Windows and attach your SSD. Your SSD should now show up. If it does not, go into the Windows > Administrative Tools > Computer Management, and format the disk.

Comment: Hard drive isn't bad.

Comment: I bought this one month ago.

Comment: Just because you bought it a month ago doesn't mean it isn't bad. Newness does not mean anything, you can get a bad hard drive right out of the factory. Yours took 1 month to show defective, but this is the normal time frame to see if a hard drive is defective. Most defective hard drives die within the first few months.

Comment: Now my tablet does not install any os.

Comment: sorry, if you want to ask about your tablet please make a new question about that.

Comment: I install windows 10 because my tablet pre-installed os cannot boot.

Comment: pre-installed os is windows 10 home

Comment: That is a different question, please ask a new question about that one.

Comment: You'll need to use a working computer to troubleshoot the SSD.